# UIView layer rounded corners and -drawRect:

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is it possible to set rounded corners on an `UIView`'s layer and override `-drawRect:` at the same time? Currently the `-drawRect:` call seems to override the layer's rounded corners and make them appear angular again, even if the `-drawRect:` just contains a call to the super's `-drawRect:`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`self.opaque = NO` didn't work for me. Setting `self.layer.masksToBounds = YES` did work, however (tested on iOS 4.3):

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if( self )
    {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 6.0f;
        self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Same here.  `self.opaque = NO` didn't do it, but `masksToBounds = YES` does.

Answer (score 3):

Set the opaque property to NO. You will get your rounded corners back.

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if(self)
    {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = KCORNERRAD;
        self.opaque = NO;

    }
    return self;
}
```