# drawRect doesn't reflect changes made to layer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

The `UITableView` I am using has a custom `UItableViewCell`. This custom cell has a subview (an UIView subclass) to it. I use the `drawRect` of the custom UIView subclass to place all the text to be displayed by the cell.

And in the `drawRect` (of `UIView` subclass) I do the following

```
/*
// This piece of code is called when setNeedsDisplay is called
*/
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0f;
    self.layer.backgroundColor = [[UIColor orangeColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f;
}
```

However my custom cell is a black square like this

[image]

But I do see the intended behavior if I select the row. Like shown below

[image]

Whats going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set `self.layer.masksToBounds = YES` and (maybe) `self.opaque = NO` during your `UIView`'s (the one where `drawRect` is overridden) initialization.  (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7078911/uiview-layer-rounded-corners-and-drawrect))

Answer (score 3):

Your `drawRect:` method does not draw anything; the code that you put in there belongs in your `initWithFrame:` implementation.

You should manipulate the layer configuration in the initializer; in your `drawRect:` you should call functions of your `CGContextRef` based on the state of the view. For example, to draw some text you would use `CGContextShowTextAtPoint`, to draw some lines you would use `CGContextAddLineToPoint`, and so on.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4979192/335858) for information on the relationship between `drawRect:` and the `CALayer` of your `UIView`.

Comment: So does that mean, if I don't draw anything in drawRect, the initializations i had done in initWithFrame don't show ?

Comment: @GarryO If you do not draw anything in `drawRect:`, you should remove the method; otherwise, your rectangle will remain black.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the selection highlight of the cell by using

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing one mistake:

Please go to the view in side the UItableViewCell and check the background color it may be black or something others, Reset it to clear color then check your result,